# What is the meaning of that sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Kindly explain what could the author mean under "bring that universe from overwhelm to whelm". I've already raised question regarding the word "whelm", which was explained by FumbleFingers, but the message is still not clear.
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299263/what-is-the-meaning-of-from-overwhelm-to-whelm

Let's start from what computing and communications in general will be like in 20 or 30 years. I assume they'll be: 
•   more pervasive (seamless connectivity, internet of things, etc.), 
•   more wearable or built-in (contacts, cochlear implants, dermal displays, etc.), 
•   and we'll have new services to help us bring that universe from overwhelm to whelm.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on two SE sites -- the Management really dislikes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is an improper use of "whelm".

What he's trying to do: he's trying to say that they're taking that is a daunting task, and turning it into something more manageable.